# isinstance() not working the way I think it should

Tags: python

My program requires a user input of a list of two elements, so to check if those conditions are satisfied I used the following code:

```
start = input('Enter you start location.\nE.g. Enter "[2,5]" for x-coordinate 2 and y-coordinate  
             5.')
while isinstance(start, list) == False or len(start) != 2:
     start = input('Try again.')
```

This will never exit the while loop no matter what I input. Why?

Comment: `input` will always return a `str` object.

Comment: What makes you think the data you receive from input is a list?  It's likely string.  So that would make "2,5" which is ***3*** characters (not 2)

Comment: @J.Murray Not likely; *is*. If `start == '[2,5]'`, `len(start)` will return 5, not 3.

Comment: @mom'sSpaghettiCode In Python 2, `input` would indeed return the list `[2, 5]` rather than the string `'[2,5]'`. That is no longer true in Python 3, whose `input` function is equivalent to Python 2's `raw_input`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your `start` variable turns out to be a string:`start = "[2,5]"`, which is not a list. You can ask the user to input e.g `2,3`,
then you get `"2,3"`. You then can split it to a list using `start.split(',')`

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely not recommanded for obvious security risk, but you can use `eval`.

```py
start = eval(input('Enter you start location.\nE.g. Enter "[2,5]" for x-coordinate 2 and y-coordinate 5.'))
```

A  prefered way is by using split, but in this case ask the user to enter coordinate separated by a coma.

```py
start = input('Enter you start location.\nE.g. Enter "2,5" for x-coordinate 2 and y-coordinate 5.')
start = start.split(",")
```

### Edit as recommanded by @soyapencil comments

```py
inp_str = input('Enter you start location.\nE.g. Enter "[2,5]" for x-coordinate 2 and y-coordinate 5.')
start = [int(i) for i in iter(eval(inp_str,{}))]
```

Comment: I would recommend locally binding `eval` as follows for safety: `safe_parse = [int(i) for i in iter(eval(inp_str))]`, where `inp_str = input('Enter you start location.\nE.g. Enter "[2,5]" for x-coordinate 2 and y-coordinate 5.')`.

Comment: @soyapencil why do you believe that is safe? It is definitely not safe against untrusted input

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Woops! That snippet was missing an empty dictionary. Fixed now.